# How to create another shipping method which based on the previous shipping method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two shipping methods,

- Standard
- Express

Standard shipping method will be calculated based on the items amount and other data. In the express shipping method, I just want to add x amount. Let say if the standard shipping is 50 then it will be increased in the express 52. and if it is 60 then it will be 62. So basically increase the express shipping cost by adding 2 to standard shipping cost.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using this code. I have set the flat_rate shipping method price as 2 and then updating it by adding the standard shipping cost.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    $standardCost = 0;
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if( $rate->method_id == 'betrs_shipping'){
            $standardCost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
        }
        if( $rate->method_id == 'flat_rate'){
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost += $standardCost;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```